# JUnit sample program compiling but giving runtime error

Tags: java, linux, junit, classpath

I am starting off with JUnit in Ubuntu and tried to execute the sample program given [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_environment_setup.htm). I have also followed instructions as given in the same link. The code compiles succesfully but gives runtime error as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/JUnitCore
    at TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

So far this is what I have got. This error occurs if the `$CLASSPATH` variable isn't set to the location of the classes required by it.

```
> echo $CLASSPATH
/home/webyog/workspace/JUNIT/junit-4.11.jar:.
```

My java files and class files are in `/home/webyog/JUNIT_WORKSPACE/`  and all the libraries and the JUnit jar file is in `/home/webyog/workspace/JUNIT/`. 
I executed these in order:

```
javac TestJunit.java TestRunner.java -classpath /home/webyog/workspace/JUNIT/junit-4.11
```

(This generated 2 files `TestRunner.class` and `TestJunit.class`)

```
java TestRunner -classpath $CLASSPATH
```

(This gives the error)

What I am I missing? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried giving classpath explicitly like:                    java -cp "/home/webyog/workspace/JUNIT/junit-4.11.jar" TestRunner

Comment: how did you set your CLASSPATH?

Comment: Ys. Done that. Still the same. :(

Comment: Set classpath using export CLASSPATH=~/workspace/JUNIT/junit-4.11.jar:.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you have `/home/webyog/workspace/JUNIT/junit-4.11.jar:.` for `$CLASSPATH` but state:

> the JUnit jar file is in `/home/webyog/JUNIT/`

(note the `workspace` missing)

That could explain the error you are seeing.

Try with:

```
cd /home/webyog/JUNIT_WORKSPACE/
java -cp '/home/webyog/JUNIT/junit-4.11.jar:.' TestRunner
```

---

Also you might want to check out some build tool to make you life easier (maven, ant, gradle, ...)

Comment: I am extremely sorry. It was a mistake on my part while posting the question. It is the correct path on my machine. It still doesn't work. I am going to try using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Check the jar is in the directory used for cp, make sure it's the right jar (try to unzip for example or download again). You can also zip everything (junit jar, your sources and class) and provide that for inspection

Comment: I have unzipped the jar file. These classes are present in it.In the exact location as specified here.